# How to use multiple handwriting recognition engines in UWP?

Tags: uwp, handwriting-recognition

I want to write with a stylus on an `InkCanvas` in any supported language. The handwriting recognition is done by the `InkRecognizer` objects.

Judging by their [possible names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkrecognizer#Properties), I see that it includes English (US), French, German and Romanian. I have these 4 language packs installed on my computer, but when I write a word in any of them besides English, I see the word is not recognized. The handwriting recognition engine for German is not used (or not available) when I write "geht".

I went in [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-topic-specific-samples/archive/uwp-ink-handwriting-reco.zip) demo and added two lines of code to see the installed engines.  There were only 2, English (US) and English (Canada), when I wrote "geht", a German word.

[image]

[image]

My question is, how do I install the handwriting recognition engines? If as a user I cannot install them, why they are not available? And if they are available, why they are not used, even when I have the language pack installed?

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/convert-ink-to-text) tutorial, both Constrained handwriting recognition and International handwriting recognition sections.

I went in the Windows Settings app > Time & Language > Region and Language. I went through each language, clicked Options, and only for English there is some info about handwriting.

[image]

For the others, there was no info about Language options and handwriting.

[image]

My Windows version is 1709, which is also the minimum version supported by the app in which recognition happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing on my side, I cannot reproduce your issue. I could get handwriting recognition engines correctly of all the languages that installed with `Handwriting` package.
[image]

So that there should be nothing wrong with the code itself. I download the `Handwriting` packages just inside the options of one language you mentioned above.

> For the others, there was no info about Language options and handwriting.

The normal language options page on my side is as follows, seems that your settings missed Language options.

[image]

So that what you actually need to resolve is finding the missed settings. Please try to remove the language and re-add it by `Add a language` button on `Region & Language` page. More details you could see [Windows 10 Checklist Part 3: Language packs, speech and handwriting](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3815-region-language-settings-copy-windows-10-a.html).

If you still have issues, please check if something wrong with the system.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there was a group policy preventing the download of language options. Thank you.